# Am I oversimplifying this situation or is it really just the Pythagorean thm?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

[image: My drawing of the situation with the assumption I am drawing]

Let's say there is a big square with side length l and vertices X, B, C, D. A line AE cuts it to form pentagon ABCDE. Now if I draw a smaller square inside of this pentagon so that 2 of its vertices are on side AE of the pentagon and the other 2 are on BC and CD, am I right in using AB (a) and DE (b) to conclude that AE (s) must be sqrt(a^2 + b^2) using the Pythagorean theorem?

Comment: It depends on how you're drawing that conclusion — the diagram you're looking at is used for one of the most classic _proofs_ of the Pythagorean Theorem, by analyzing the areas of each piece of the puzzle. What is the ultimate question you're trying to solve here?

Comment: Well, it's not true for all choices of $A$ and $E$ that the other vertices of the square on $\overline{AE}$ will lie on other sides of the big square. (For instance, consider $A$ and $E$ really close to $X$.) However, **in the cases where this does happen**, the configuration has four congruent right triangles, and the Pythagorean relation holds.

Comment: Maybe off topic but if you take four copies of any right triangle and form a square out of them similar to your diagram you can prove the Pythagorean theorem by taking the area of the square in two different ways and setting them equal to each other.